# Jax Jit Makes Function Run out of Memory

Tags: python, jit, jax

When I add the @jax.jit decorator to the repl_arr function I get "MemoryError: bad allocation". For refence, signal_arr and scaled_noise_arr are 120x120 jax.numpy arrays.

```
@jax.jit # Works if commented out
def repl_arr(signal_arr, scaled_noise_arr, xs_sub, ys_sub):
    signal_arr = signal_arr.at[xs_sub, ys_sub].set(scaled_noise_arr[xs_sub, ys_sub])
    return signal_arr

def combine_signal_noise_repl(c_key, signal_arr, noise_arr, repl_perc=0.65):
    """
    Replaces repl_perc of the signal array with the noise array values randomly
    """
    n_key, subkey = jax.random.split(c_key)
    valid_indices = jnp.array(list(range(signal_arr.size))) #inds of indices
    n_samples = int(repl_perc*signal_arr.size)
    chosen_indices = jax.random.choice(subkey, valid_indices, 
                                       shape=(n_samples,), replace=False)
    xy_inds = jnp.array(list(product( \
        jnp.arange(signal_arr.shape[0]), jnp.arange(signal_arr.shape[1]))))
    
    xs_sub, ys_sub = zip(*xy_inds[chosen_indices])
    scaled_noise_arr = scale01(noise_arr)
    combined_arr = repl_arr(signal_arr, scaled_noise_arr, xs_sub, ys_sub)
    return n_key, combined_arr
```

Previously I was trying to do:

```
@jax.jit
def combine_signal_noise_repl(c_key, signal_arr, noise_arr, repl_perc=0.65):
    """
    Replaces repl_perc of the signal array with the noise array values randomly
    """
    n_key, subkey = jax.random.split(c_key)
    valid_indices = jnp.array(list(range(signal_arr.size))) #inds of indices
    n_samples = int(repl_perc*signal_arr.size)
    chosen_indices = jax.random.choice(subkey, valid_indices, 
                                       shape=(n_samples,), replace=False)
    xy_inds = jnp.array(list(product( \
        jnp.arange(signal_arr.shape[0]), jnp.arange(signal_arr.shape[1]))))
    
    xs_sub, ys_sub = zip(*xy_inds[chosen_indices])
    scaled_noise_arr = scale01(noise_arr)
    signal_arr = signal_arr.at[xs_sub, ys_sub].set(scaled_noise_arr[xs_sub, ys_sub])
    return signal_arr
```

Which got me some "LLVM ERROR: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32NB relocation requires an ordered section layout" error that I have about 0 understanding of. Not sure what the issue is here. Commenting out my jiting makes either snippit of code work just fine, but they're slow; and if my past experience with jax is any indication, it'll be the setting array values that is the slow part of the function.

For completenesses sake, I call the function:

```
@jax.jit
def scale01(x):
    return (x-jnp.min(x))/(jnp.max(x)-jnp.min(x))
```

This seems to have no issue, including when jit-ed.

Comment: As a minor note, I also tried the decorator @partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=['repl_perc']) for the 2nd ex of combine_signal_noise_repl that doesn't call repl_arr; it was taking forever so I cancelled it (eg closed python tab bc the whole thing stopped responding).